# SpringBoot, JConsole and Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I am trying to get some kind of monitoring my SpringBoot app with JMX and Zabbix. I added to my app

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file= path to jmx.password
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=path to jmx.access
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=host ip
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=64355
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=64355
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="path to keystore"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keystore password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="path to truststore"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=truststore password
```

Wheh I try to run Zabbix jmx agent with Service URL service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostIP:64355/jmxrmi I have an error

```
non-jrmp server at remote endpoint
```

in zabbix_java_gateway.log

If I set hostIP:64355 I have

```
 Service URL must start with service:jmx:
```

When I try to connect from JConsole I have the same error with service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostIP:64355/jmxrmi as in Zabbix, but wher I put hostIP:64355 to "Remote Process" field, everithing is ok

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix isn't able to handle the RMI registry over TLS.  Setting `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=false` and `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true` should get the most amount of encryption possible with the current versions of Zabbix.